# How to implement web-based installer?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

Guys how can I implement a web installer for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into ClickOnce deployment:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx

You can publish your application to a web server from Visual Studio, or you can publish to a folder and copy the files to another destination.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using VS, so I have been using Advanced Installer from http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-web-installation.html

Such feature is a blessing for evaluation packages, which are notoriously difficult to maintain across the gazillion software repositories. With such a scheme, all is needed to make sure the trial is up to date is to update the online package.